Python import path when executed through symlink
I have a project directory that looks like this:
project/
├── my_input.py
├── run_me.py
└── test
    ├── my_input.py
    └── run_me.py -> ../run_me.py

The run_me.py script imports from input.py. My expectation is that the symlinked test/run_me.py would import from test/my_input.py but what I actually find is that it imports from the directory of its target. What can I do to get my expectation?
Execution example:
run_me.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from my_input import *

my_input.py:
print("imported from my_input.py")

test/my_input.py
print("imported from test/my_input.py")             

output of ./run_me.py when working directory is test:
imported from my_input.py

Don't use valid input for Python. Use some other name.

@toyotaSupra names changed but behavior is the same

cd ..; ./test/my_input.py ?

run_me.py is the executable, and unfortunately ./test/run_me.py also doesn't change the behavior

I've found that import uses sys.path to search for modules. The first path (always?) is the directory of the file/symlink target instead of the symlink. I've added
import sys, os
sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

to the start of run_me.py to inform import to look at the symlink's directory instead.
